# "To the science is known about 200 types of E-coli"

Tags: passive-voice

I want to say in passive voice that in our days the sience knows more than 200 types of something.

Is the following sentence correct?

> "To the science is known about 200 types of E-coli"

Comment: Drop the "the".

Comment: "To science in nowadays **are** known about 200 types of E-coli" will be ok?

Comment: No. See @Eran's answer. If you want to include "nowadays", put it at the end. "About 200 types of E-coli are known to science nowadays." Or if you want to emphasize it, put it at the beginning and include a comma. "Nowadays, about 200 types of E-coli are known to science."

Answer (score 2):

200 types are in plural, so it should be:

"About 200 types of E-coli **are** known to science."